# How can I manually calculate the value of a ValueAnimator at any given time

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a value animator that I want to use use to calculate different properties, I want to use just one and manually calculate the values I want given the fraction of completion of the value animator

for example this is a custom class that I use to get how far the scale has gone

```
private class ScaleUpdateListener implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        currentScale = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

        float fraction = animation.getAnimatedFraction();

            float translateX = // need to figure how far to translate between 200 and 100 given fraction

        invalidate();

    }

}
```

But I also want to calculate a translate value that goes from something like 200 to 100.

So just thinking about it at fraction .5 half way through id want to some how calculate 150, half way between 100 and 200, i just can't figure out the formula for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function to tell what percentage of the way from a to b a number x is?

(x-a)/(b-a)

Comment: No I have the percentage I need the value between two numbers a and b

Comment: So you have (x-a)/(b-a)=percentage.  Solve for x.  Simple algebra.